# Dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' Not Found

Tags: android, build.gradle

I started to work with Gradle. And when I add this code into build.gradle;

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Im getting this error:

```
"Dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' Not Found"
```

So, how can I add appcompat support to my project?

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.project.package"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.27"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar')

}
```

Comment: Did you try clean & build?

Comment: @Ricardo Im using AIDE and I did.

Comment: Add this and please keep your internet on while run application 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

Comment: @SuhasBachewar still not working. How can  get jar or aar or project of library?

Comment: Did you update your sdk manager with support libraries repository?

Comment: When you add dependency, gardle online build setting automatically download the v7 .jar file.Also Check once your gradle build is online or offline.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar Im using AIDE Android IDE app. It is updating oftenly. But It doesnt downloading. Can I reach v7 jar file manually?

Comment: Yes you can.Go to project directory you can find there and make sure your gradle should be in  offline build.